# Bootstrap dynamic hours refreshing issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

**tl;dr** : I want to refresh time inside the popover without having to toggle it again (by clicking). When it's opened, it update the time.

I'm trying to make my ***popover*** refresh but I can't find a way to do it. I have dynamic hours in it, it needs to change every seconds. It is the only content that will need to be refresh even when the page is active. The other will update if we toggle it, if I need to update it too. I tried to search many ways to do it but couldn't find any clues.

```
<div class="col-md-8" style="padding-top:50px;position: relative;">


            <canvas class="canvas" id="canvas" width="650px" height="450px">Votre
                navigateur ne supporte pas le canevas.
            </canvas>
             

            <input type="image" src="images/plane.png" id="planeimg" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="top"
                title="Données du trajet" data-html="true"/>

            <!-- POPOVER CONTENT -->
            <div id="popover-content" class="hide">
                <span>Départ : </span> <span id="departPopover">Montreal</span> <br/>
                <span>Arrivée : </span> <span id="arrivePopover">Toronto</span> <br/>
                <span>Prochaine ville : </span> <span id="nextCity">Toronto</span> <br/>
                <span>Vitesse : 500 km/h</span> <br/>
                <span>Temps restant : </span> <span id="timeLeft">2</span> <span>h</span> <br/>
                <span>Heure : </span> <span id="timeHours"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Here is my Javascript code :

```
$(function(){
    // Enables popover
    $("[data-toggle=popover]").popover({
        html: true,
        content: function() {
            return $('#popover-content').html();
        }
    });
});


// TIME FUNCTION
function startTime() {
    var today = new Date();
    var h = today.getHours();
    var m = today.getMinutes();
    var s = today.getSeconds();
    m = checkTime(m);
    s = checkTime(s);
    document.getElementById('timeHours').innerHTML =
    h + ":" + m + ":" + s;

    var t = setTimeout(startTime, 500);
}

function checkTime(i) {
    if (i < 10) {i = "0" + i};  // add zero in front of numbers < 10
    return i;
}
```

Thanks for the help guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's simple solution for updating clock:

```js
function startTime() {
    var currentTime = new Date();
    var h = currentTime.getHours();
    var m = currentTime.getMinutes();
    var s = currentTime.getSeconds();
    
    // Pad the minutes and seconds with leading zeros   
    m = ( m < 10 ? "0" : "") + m;
    s = ( s < 10 ? "0" : "") + s;

    // AM or PM (for 24h delete this)     
    var time = (h < 12) ? "AM" : "PM";
    
    // 12 hour format (for 24h delete this)
    h = (h > 12) ? h - 12 : h;
    
    // Conver an hours form 0 to 12
    h = (h == 0) ? 12 : h;
  
    // Visual compose
    var display = h + ":" + m + ":" + s + " " + time;
    // (for 24h )
    // var display = h + ":" + m + ":" + s;
    
    $("#timeHours").html(display);
  
}

$(document).ready(function(){
  setInterval('startTime()', 1000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="timeHours"></span>
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for the support, but with this code, the popover doesn't show anymore. :( It's INSIDE a popover too.

Comment: It's just for the time if ur popover doesn't show it's because u have to delete enabling call.. It's just gonna update value in `$('#timeHors')` element

Comment: I do update it, with the original code I wrote in the OP. It works, but I need to reclick on it to toggle it again and again and again to see the panel change. My question here is how to make it dynamic, that I don't need to toggle it to see the time updating.

Comment: The code is automatically updating time every second

Comment: But it is not showing in the Bootstrap popover. The code IS working. The popover ISN'T updating dynamically...